# how to carry forward a value that was available before switchmap?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-observables

I have an rxjs that pass an id, and I need to call an api, the api will return some data and I need to process that data regards to the projectId that wasa available before the switchMap.

if I map it to `{projectId, api: this.http.get('/api/projects/'+projectId)}` will not work like switchmap.

```js
selectedProject$.pipe(
    switchMap(projectId=> this.http.get('/api/projects/'+projectId)), 
    map(data=> this.createChart(
                    projectId, /* I need the project id that was available before the switchMap */
                        data))
)
```

I know I can set `tap(projectId=> this.selectedProjectId=projectId)` and use it later, but I want to know a way to handle it with rxjs

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to pass `projectId` down the chain, you can chain `map` after `http.get` to extract that data for downstream

```
switchMap(projectId=> this.http.get('/api/projects/'+projectId).pipe(map(data=> ({data,projectId})),
 map(({data,projectId})=>....
```